# Qmessagebox, Error: argument 1 has unexpected type 'Ui_MainWindow'

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qmessagebox

With QTDesigner in version 5, I have done a mainwindow, now i like to create a QMessagebox on click on the Button in the mainwindow.

I got an error : argument 1 has unexpected type 'Ui_MainWindow'

I have no idea why this is not working, hopefully you can help me i'm really new to programming:

The line i added:

```
self.pushButton.clicked.connect(QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self, "Empty String", "Please enter day."))
```

to:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(320, 240)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 160, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 320, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self, "Empty String", "Please enter day."))
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct number of spaces (called indentation)  before every line is critical in Python. Enter 8 spaces before the line that you have added.

Comment: thx alex i just have had a bracket to much, but now i get a new error

Comment: The proplem with indents are not there anymore but it's still not working and i don't find a solution yet. I edited the post above. I'm pretty sure the problem is that i don't really understand classes well and there is a problem with inherit?

Answer (score 0):

Just replace in your code

```py
self.pushButton.clicked.connect(QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self, "Empty String", "Please enter day."))
```

by

```py
self.pushButton.clicked.connect(
    QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
        self.centralwidget, "Empty String", "Please enter day."
    )
)
```

Observe that `self.centralwidget` is declared in your ui and is of type `QWidget`. If it doesn't work, make contact that sends a working example.